# Как при закрытии одного окна сделать другое окно редактируемым?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qdialog

Есть главное окно с кнопкой, при нажатии которой открывается другое - информационное окно. При этом главное окно остается открытым, но становится нередактируемым (`setEnabled(False)`).

Как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии этого информационного окна с помощью кнопки, главное окно вновь становилось редактируемым?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 330, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.calc_prop)
        self.EWM = None

    def calc_prop(self):
        self.EWM = UiErrorWindowMod('Ошибка')
        self.EWM.show()
        self.setEnabled(False)

    def set_enable_true(self):
        self.setEnabled(True)


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(320, 240)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Dialog)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 301, 181))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 281, 151))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 200, 71, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setCheckable(False)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Ошибка"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "ОК"))


class UiErrorWindowMod(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, error_message):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.label.setText(error_message)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close_error_window)

    def close_error_window(self):
        self.close()
        MainWindow.set_enable_true(self)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MW = MainWindow()
MW.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `QDialog` является базовым классом диалоговых окон.

> int QDialog::[**exec()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec)
>
> Отображает диалоговое окно как модальное диалоговое окно,
> блокируя его до тех пор, пока пользователь не закроет его. 
> Функция возвращает результат DialogCode.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 330, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(320, 240)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Dialog)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 301, 181))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 281, 151))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 200, 71, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setCheckable(False)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Ошибка"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "ОК"))


#class UiErrorWindowMod(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
# -------------------->           v^v^v^v^v^v
class UiErrorWindowMod( QtWidgets.QDialog,      Ui_Dialog):             # !!! +++ QDialog
    def __init__(self, error_message):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.label.setText(error_message)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close_error_window)

    def close_error_window(self):
        self.close()
# ???        MainWindow.set_enable_true(self)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.calc_prop)
# ???        self.EWM = None

    def calc_prop(self):
        self.EWM = UiErrorWindowMod('Ошибка')
        
#        self.EWM.show()
        self.EWM.exec_()                                             # !!! +++ exec_() 
        
# ???        self.setEnabled(False)

# ???    def set_enable_true(self):
# ???        self.setEnabled(True)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]